# Problema com script simples de ordenamento Json JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou aprendendo JavaScript e estou criando um script que precisa colocar um arquivo Json em ordem alfabética e imprimir na tela se tem item repetido e se existir mostrar qual.

Já olhei diversas perguntas e ate agora não consegui achar uma conclusão, se alguém me ajudar vou ser muito grato

Esse é meu script HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="data"></ul>
        <div id="app"></div>"
        <button  onClick="console.log(dados, uniqNames)"> Rotate </button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


const dados = {
"alimentos": 
    {

      "carne": "carne",
      "arroz": "feijão",
      
},
"bebidas": 
    {

      "agua": "gelada",
      "leite": "nescau",
      
},
    
    }

    // Pega os nome 
    const names = dados.alimentos.map( identificar => identificar.CLIENT_ID )
    const names = dados.bebidas.map( bebidas => bebidas.CLIENT_ID )
    

    // Filtrar nomes repetidos
    const uniqNames = names.filter((name, index, self) => self.indexOf(name) === index)
    
    //Coloca em ordem alfabetica 
    uniqNames.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.nome > b.nome) ? 1 : ((b.nome > a.nome) ? -1 : 0);
        
});

    //Passa os nomes verificados 
    let resultados = [];
    uniqNames.forEach( uName => {
    names.forEach( name => {
        if (name == uName) {
            resultados[uName] = (resultados[uName] > 0 ? resultados[uName] : 0)  + 1
        }
        
    })
    
})
    console.log(dados, uniqNames)
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

o resultado esperado é
colocar em ordem alfabética o Json
traduçao
car:carros
leite:milk

traducão_2
amor:love
car:carros

(Imprimir mensagem que está repetida)
mensagem: car:carro está repetido

```js
<script>
const dados = {
"tradução": 
    {

      "car": "carros",
      "leite": "milk",
      
},
"tradução_2": 
    {
      "car": "carros",
      "amor": "love",
      
},
    
    }

    // Pega os nome 
    const names = dados.tradução.map( tradução => tradução.CLIENT_ID )

    // Filtrar nomes repetidos
    const uniqNames = names.filter((name, index, self) => self.indexOf(name) === index)
    
    //Coloca em ordem alfabetica 
    uniqNames.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.nome > b.nome) ? 1 : ((b.nome > a.nome) ? -1 : 0);
        
});

    //Passa os nomes verificados 
    let resultados = [];
    uniqNames.forEach( uName => {
    names.forEach( name => {
        if (name == uName) {
            resultados[uName] = (resultados[uName] > 0 ? resultados[uName] : 0)  + 1
        }
        
    })
    
})
    console.log(dados, uniqNames)
    </scrtipt>
```

Comment: O "arquivo Json" que você quer ordenar é a variável dados? Porque ela esta nesse formato? Não seria melhor fazer assim: dados ={"alimentos": ["carne", "arroz", "feijao"], "bebidas": ["agua", "leite"]}

Comment: sim dessa forma eu fiz e deu certo, porém eu preciso fazer em um Json especifico que está nesse formato

Comment: O formato que está na pergunta não faz sentido. Um objeto tem chave e valor. O jeito que você colocou está chave "carne", valor "carne", depois chave "arroz", valor "feijão". Concorda que não faz sentido? Porque você diz que precisa ser assim? Um outro erro no seu código está logo abaixo, você esta declarando `names` duas vezes e tentando acessar uma propriedade que não existe: CLIENT_ID

Comment: esse Json é uma lista enorme eu só coloquei esse exemplo pelo formato, pois se trata de um Json de tradução então por exemplo ele ta assim chave"carro": valor "car" eu preciso imprimir a chave e o valor não só o valor, e relação ao names eu corrigi porem ele só pega o "alimentos" gostaria de ler tbm "bebida" essa é a duvida tbm

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado? Por favor, crie um [mcve], não precisa de todo esse código para demonstrar o problema. Por exemplo, o `<head>` do HTML em nada influencia na sua pergunta...

Comment: Não tem como ordenar chaves de objetos, ou seja, não é possível fazer o que quer e manter a estrutura desse json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Vou tentar lhe ajudar. Alguns pontos importantes, antes de mais nada:

- Um JSON *não tem ordem*. Ele é um estrutura associativa (dicionário ou hash-table), onde os itens são identificados por "chaves", então, no fundo, se eu montar uma estrutura...

```js
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}
```

...`a` não vem antes de `b` e `b` não vem antes de `a`. Isso é uma decisão interna do JS e, se você percorrer as chaves e elas aparecerem nesta ordem, trate isso como uma *coincidência* e não uma obrigação.

- Derivado do ponto acima você pode notar que, então, não é possível *ordernar* um JSON. O que você quer fazer é *percorrê-lo*  (traverse) em uma ordem específica.
- Também é interessante notar que o JSON é uma estrutura em árvore. Isso significa que existe uma raiz (em seu exemplo, `dados`) e cada elemento tem vários filhos, i.e., é uma *hierarquia*. Isso significa que na hora de ordenar você precisa tomar uma decisão, se você mostra os itens *por profundidade* ou *por largura*. Vou assumir que o que você precisa é **por profundidade**, que é o mais comum.

```js
// exemplo
{
  "1": {
    "1.1": {
      "1.1.1": {},
      "1.1.2": {},
    },
    "1.2": {
      "1.2.1": {},
      "1.2.2": {},
    },
  "2": {
    "2.1": {
      "2.1.1": {},
    },
    "2.2": {
      "2.2.1": {}
    }
  } 
}
```

*Ordem por profundidade:*
1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.2, 2.2.1
*Ordem por largura:*
1, 2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2.1.1., 2.2.1

Note como na ordem por profunidade primeiro *descemos* na árvore, enquanto na largura olhamos os irmãos primeiro.

---

Posto estes pontos, o que você precisa fazer em alto nível é:

- Recuperar as chaves que você deseja percorrer,
- Ordenar essas chaves,
- Exibí-las (ou, se preferir, guardá-las em um vetor/array, que tem ordenação).
- Percorrer os filhos - neste ponto, é importante ver se o item tem filhos.

Então veja:

```js
const dados = {
  "alimentos": {
    "carne": "carne",
    "arroz": "feijão",    
  },
  "bebidas": {
    "agua": "gelada",
    "leite": "nescau",      
  },
};

/** Percorre por profundidade e imprime o resultado */
function depthFirstTraversal(data) {
  // recupera as chaves do objeto no nível atual
  const chaves = Object.keys(data);
  // ordena as chaves
  const chavesOrdenadas = chaves.sort();
   
  // percorre as chaves
  for (const chave of chavesOrdenadas) {
    // imprime a chave atual
    console.log(chave); 
    // recupera os filhos desta
    const filhos = data[chave];
    // verifica se o item atual tem filhos ou se já é a tradução
    if (typeof filhos == "object") {
      // desce percorrendo os filhos o item atual
      depthFirstTraversal(filhos);
    }
  }
}

// executa
depthFirstTraversal(dados);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder, já deu uma luz. 
Más dessa forma ele só imprimi as chaves "alimentos e bebidas" a minha duvida é como abrir e ordenar oq esta dentro dessas chaves

Obrigado por compartilhar o conhecimento isso que aprendi agora vai ser muito útil

Comment: @glen tem um erro no código, está corrigido. Eu usava "filhos" antes de declarar. Javascript, uma delícia de linguagem. :(

Comment: deu certo esse modo, agora a unica duvida é como imprimir apenas os repetidos